# chartJS the canvas become very big

Tags: angular, canvas, chart.js

I am using chartJS in Angular2 to draw table, and the canvas was set height as 250px, but when the data is ready, the canvas became vary big, with the height more than 10000px. Anyone know the possible reason? Thanks! (there is the screenshoot behind the code.)

```
<div class="chart">
  <canvas id="brand_interests" style="height:250px"></canvas>
</div>
```

[the canvas became huge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4S8c7.png)

Comment: <canvas id="brand_interests"  width="300" height="300"></canvas> also check the class you using for parent div to you are not setting height and width there.

Comment: hi, MMK, set the style of outer div can help set the size of canvas, like<div class="chart" style="height:400px; width:1300px;">, but if the browser window change size, it can't not work properly. At first without set style of outer div, only set the height of canvas, it can work, but later, don't know why, the problem i ask happen.